# <title> tag and favicon aren't correctly showed by Google Search

Tags: php, html, seo, googlebot

I'll go straight to the point.

For a few days I've been working on the SEO on my website and I noticed that the favicon still isn't showed by Google Search and that the `<title>` tag is showed wrong! See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3JBU.png).

About the favicon, I have it in my root folder and the tests [on realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?protocol=https&site=www.blogsonic.org) and [on the Google favicon checker](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=blogsonic.org) don't return any error.

About the title, the problem is that it's shown like "Blogsonic: Home", while it should be "Home | Blogsonic". The weird thing, as you can see on the screenshot, is that the title on the About page works fine!

Here's is how my header file looks:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?= $title; ?> | Blogsonic</title>
    <?php 
        if (isset($meta_description)) {
    ?>
        <meta name="description" content="<?= $meta_description; ?>">
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="<?= base_url('it'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?= base_url('public/img/blogsonic-social-preview.png'); ?>">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1280">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="640">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?= base_url('public/icon/apple-touch-icon.png'); ?>">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<?= base_url('public/icon/favicon-32x32.png'); ?>">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<?= base_url('public/icon/favicon-16x16.png'); ?>">
    <link rel="manifest" href="<?= base_url('public/icon/site.webmanifest'); ?>">
    <!-- <link rel="mask-icon" href="<?= base_url('public/icon/safari-pinned-tab.svg'); ?>" color="#5bbad5"> -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= base_url('favicon.ico'); ?>">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#426e9c">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="<?= base_url('public/icon/browserconfig.xml'); ?>">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <script src="<?= base_url('public/jquery/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('public/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('public/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'); ?>"/>
    <script src="<?= base_url('public/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'); ?>"></script>
</head>
```

> **Note**: If you think that embedding PHP in HTML is bad, you should see the rest of my code... Jokes aside, I just don't care. This is literally my first web project ever and now I'm more focused on using it as a "playground" to test things.

I've also used the Google Search Console to update the pages and everything looks fine. As you can see from this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGXXZ.png) the last updated date is October 2nd, 03:22 AM.

If you need me to show you other parts of my code, you can ask me here and I'll be very happy to answer you, or you can see the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/antogno/blogsonic).

Can anyone help me? **Thanks in advance!**

> **Note**: English is not my mother tongue. Forgive me if I've made some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The size of your favicon must be a multiple of 48 pixels square, for example:
48 x 48 px
96 x 96 px
144 x 144 px

Don't use 16x16 size, Google will resize it automatically.

[Define a favicon to show in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/favicon-in-search)

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48" href="public/icon/favicon-48x48.png">
```

Comment: It already is 48 x 48 pixels: https://www.blogsonic.org/favicon.ico

Comment: Try doing the PNG version, I don't know how long it takes Google to update the result. If it doesn't work, the icon may have been misinterpreted by Google robots.